# Python Pandas export data

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I am using python pandas to process some data. I have exported my data to an excel file using the below code.

```
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('Data.xlsx');
wrong_data.to_excel(writer,"Names which are wrong", index = False);
writer.save();
```

However, when I open the excel workbook, it keeps showing that there is a formula in the excel file. The thing is that I am always overriding the workbook and hence am unclear where this error is coming from. Does anyone know how to resolve this?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="true"?>

-<recoveryLog xmlns="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/spreadsheetml/2006/main">

    <logFileName>error058920_06.xml</logFileName>

    <summary>Errors were detected in file 'C:\Users\adrlee\Desktop\Python files\Data.xlsx'</summary>


    -<removedRecords summary="Following is a list of removed records:">

    <removedRecord>Removed Records: Formula from /xl/worksheets/sheet1.xml part</removedRecord>

    </removedRecords>

    </recoveryLog>
```

Comment: Can you give an example of your pandas DataFrame which you try to export? I guess, you have some troubling data within your DataFrame which can't be exported appropriately. You may also export directly via `df.to_excel("Data.xlsx", index=False)`.

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to work with the output data in MS Excel, it is easier to work with CSV files.

[Pandas.to_csv](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html) is able to export dataframe to a CSV file. After opening the CSV file in MS Excel, you can do whatever you want.  When saving the data, you have the option to save it to xlsx file or stay in CSV files.